# My Android app (made with App Inventor) has a virus?

Tags: android, malware, virus, app-inventor

So I recently published an app that I made with App Inventor. It is a very simple App. However, I have received complaints that it is marked to have Viruses or Malware by multiple Android Security Apps on other people's phones. However, I am not really sure why. I saw a thread similar to mine, except he actually wrote the physical code for his app, he didn't use App Inventor. [My Android app is reported to have a virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490400/my-android-app-is-reported-to-have-a-virus)

I'm confused because I truly didn't put anything in the app that would harm any device. Does it have something to do with App Inventor? I've downloaded and used the app on many devices and it works perfectly fine.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it has a virus?

Comment: Does your app use the texting component? This is listed on one of the [App Inventor troubleshooting pages](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/troubleshooting.html) as something that's known to cause a false positive with at least one virus checker.

Comment: Tanis.7x, "I have received complaints that it is marked to have Viruses or Malware by multiple Android Security Apps on other people's phones."  On certain devices, certain antivirus or antimalware apps claim that my app has a virus or malware (though I am almost positive this isn't true. I can't imagine how it could be).

Comment: Matt Gibson, that could very well be the issue because it does use the texting component. Thank you so much for your input and for sending me that link!

Comment: see also [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/false$20positive) and report the false positive to that virus checker provider to update their signature list...

Answer (score 5):

All apps made by AppInventor look a lot alike, and there's a ton of boilerplate code. If a malware analyst was lazy or in a rush, it would be easy to write a detection signature that was too broad and hit on most AppInventor apps. This is my guess.

Also, once an AV company says your app is malware, others will assume it's true and write detection signatures for your app as well, with even less scrutiny than the original analyst.

I've analyzed malware made with AppInventor and personally know how difficult it is to write concise signatures for it. ;)

You should contact the company directly and explain your situation. You can periodically upload your app to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) to check if it's been removed from their signature databases.